# Got one point per vote on one question

Tags: support, reputation

Don't know what's wrong:

[Webservice Wants Byte[] - How do I send that from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903672/webservice-wants-byte-how-do-i-send-that-from-php/1903678#1903678)

I was upvoted two times on this question, yet have gained only 5 points?! It's shown in the reputation overview as a small 5 (number of votes), then no number indicating the points given (just empty). Other answers today are upvoted as they should.

Any clue?!

Answer (score 4):

You may have reached your reputation cap (200 points per day).

Comment: Nope. Just 40 points or something today

Comment: Ah well I was wrong (-:

Answer (score 4):

Check out your reputation graph:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/107642?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top

Looks like you got 170 or so rep from another question today (likely a bounty award):

[How to show Selected linkbutton amongs set of linkbuttons in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848704/1862249#1862249)

Comment: Ah f** now I see :-) default reputation screen seems broken or something, shows 43 unless you click on it, then it shows all of it.